# Remove empty cells from combobox and allow headings to be in the list but not clickable

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I have been trying to get rid of the empty cells in my combobox. I used a selected range of cells, in which there are empty cells, but can't seem to remove them. Here's my code:

```
Private sub userform_initialize() 
With Worksheets("Listing")
SearchPPComboBox.List = .Range("D4:D6" & .Range("D" &   
Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End with 
End sub
```

Also, I want to display my headings to separate and categorise the options in my combobox but how do I make them not clickable by user?

Comment: you could try and use an if statement to say that when adding the values from your range if the value = "" then dont add it else add it to the list. It might take slightly longer to do but it should work. You can use the .AddItem to do this. Is this what you mean??

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. But.. how do I code that. So if one of the cell in the range is empty then I use .select function and delete from searchPPComboBox.list? So these codes should come after my end with? I tried this but it gave me error. @GBSingh

Comment: Did my solution work?? If it did could you please accept it please so that it can be marked as solved. Thanks. @Gwen

Answer (score 0):

Below I have put a working bit of code that will find the length of the list including the bland spaces and then will add them to the comboBox while ignoring the blank spaces. I have assumed that your data is in the column A so just change this value with the column letter of where your data is.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim listLength As Integer
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Listing")
    listLength = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<==== finds the length of the list
    For x = 1 To listLength
        If wks.Cells(x, 1) <> "" Then '<=== ignores the blank spaces
           With SearchPPComboBox '<=== name of your comboBox
               .AddItem (wks.Cells(x, 1).Value) '<==== adds it to the list
            End With
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

Let me know if this works :)